# What is a word for the 'glue that binds (subject) together'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word that ascribes one underlying argument as the common characteristic of three arguments... appreciate your help :)

Comment: A sample sentence showing how the word/phrase might be used would be helpful.

Comment: You could say the arguments have a common thread.